# globals() does not work with concurrent.futures module?

Tags: python, global-variables, concurrent.futures

**This is my code without concurrent.futures:**

```
import finviz

def finvizxl(ticker):
        data = finviz.get_stock(ticker)
        globals()[ticker] = data

finvizxl('AAPL')

print(AAPL)
```

`print(AAPL)`
returns stock information on AAPL using the finviz module and the finviz.get_stock method. The globals() function converted my 'AAPL' string to a variable to store `data`

**This is my code with concurrent.futures:**

```
import finviz
import concurrent.futures

def finvizxl(ticker):
    data = finviz.get_stock(ticker)
    globals()[ticker] = data
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        x = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GME']
        executor.map(finvizxl, x)

print(AAPL)
```

**My Goal is to run my function `finvizxl()` concurrently and store `data` in the converted strings `'AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GME'` respectively, that way when i type `print(aapl)`, the stock information for the respective ticker will be returned.** However, i am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'AAPL' is not defined
```

When i put `print(AAPL)` in the function instead,

```
def finvizxl(ticker):
    data = finviz.get_stock(ticker)
    locals()[ticker] = list(data.values())
    print(AAPL)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        x = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GME']
        executor.map(finvizxl, x)
```

The program runs but nothing is returned.

However, when i do this:

```
def finvizxl(ticker):
    data = finviz.get_stock(ticker)
    locals()[ticker] = list(data.values())
    print(locals()[ticker])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        x = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GME']
        executor.map(finvizxl, x)
```

All 3 of my tickers `['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GME']` have their information returned in the terminal.

I am probably missing something basic as i just started learning python. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you're using the process pool, no.  Each pool item has its own process, with a completely separate Python interpreter and a completely separate memory space.  `concurrent` tries to shuffle over the things you need, but there is no live connection.

If you need to ship results back, you might consider using a `multiprocessing.Queue`.  That knows how to marshal things across the process boundary.